# Just don't understand the point of these typedefs

Tags: c, typedef

When trying to discover something in the code of some open source C projects, I often see this kind of typedef:

```
typedef struct _StructA StructA;
typedef struct _LinusTorvalds LinusTorvalds;
```

Why not directly define and use StructA, just StructA, instead of defining _*StructA* then "typedef" it?
What's the point of this "_" technique?

Comment: Note that the underscore has nothing to do with this technique. `typedef struct StructA StructA;` would work as well. C uses 'tags' for naming structs, and those tags can have the same name as a typedef'd type.

Comment: I think a LinusTorvalds typedef is a bad example, as he doesn't like typedefs: http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git;a=blob;f=Documentation/CodingStyle#l268  :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In C, a struct must be used as:

```
struct _StructA my_variable;
```

…i.e., you must type `struct` not only when you define the `struct`, but also every time you use it. The `typedef` eliminates the typing of `struct` when you use it (but not when you define it: there is no way to eliminate that). With a `typedef` then, declaring an instance of the `struct` becomes:

```
StructA my_variable;
```

Now, that doesn't completely explain the `_StructA`/`StructA` business in the defining of the `struct`/`typedef`, as you can do this:

```
typedef struct {
    ...
} StructA;
```

…here, we take an anonymous `struct` and immediately feed it to `typedef`. But using this method, you can't use the `struct` inside itself, as it doesn't (yet) have a name. For that, you need something like:

```
typedef struct _Foo {
    int data;
    struct _Foo *next;
} Foo;
```

Comment: "it eliminates the typing of ..." and then it looks like .. give an example to show the advantage. the 2nd snippet shows how to typedef an "anonymous" struct ... you should mention that somewhere (it conflicts a bit with the statement of 'no need to type').

Comment: thanks mate, I got it. It's so simple and this question is so stupid ^^! C++ sometimes makes my C mad :)

Answer (score 3):

In C, when you define a struct type:

```
struct StructA {
    int foo;
    double bar;
};
```

the type's name is `struct StructA`, not just `StructA`.  (C++ lets you refer to the type as just `StructA`; C++ is a different language.

If you insist on having a one-word name for it, you can use a typedef (which, we should note, creates a new name for an existing type, not a new type):

```
typedef struct StructA StructA;
```

Now you can refer to the type either as `StructA` or as `struct StructA`.

These can be combined into a single declaration:

```
typedef struct StructA {
    int foo;
    double bar;
} StructA;
```

Note that I used the same identifier for the struct tag and for the typedef.  Since they're in different namespaces, this is perfectly valid.

On the other hand, my own preference is to omit the typedef altogether, and just refer to the type as `struct StructA`.

Incidentally, the names `_StructA` and `_LinusTorvalds` in your question are reserved to the implementation, and should not be used in your own code.  In general, identifiers starting with an underscore should be avoided.  (It's not uncommon to use such identifiers, but it's wrong, unless the code is part of the C implementation itself.)

To summarize: The typedef is necessary only if you want to have a one-word name for the type (which isn't really required) -- and if you do use a typedef, there's no real reason to use different identifiers for the typedef and the struct tag.

Comment: +1, but you forgot a `typedef` in your 3rd snipset. Also as a nitpick, the type is `struct StructA` in C++, too. C++ only allows you to omit the `struct` if there is no ambiguity, that is no other identifier with that name is declared in the same scope. Think of `struct stat` as an example.

Comment: this type of typedef is used extensively in the source code of Glib/Gtk and the ibus library :|

Answer (score 1):

It provides the convenience of not using the `struct` keyword everytime you declare variables of the structure.

Without typedef:

```
struct _StructA obj;
```

With typedef:

```
StructA obj;
```

Answer (score 0):

It could reduce the dependency to a certain data structure. E.g. if you ever want to use `StructB` (maybe containing more fields) instead of `StructA`, you need to change just one line, not hundreds.